# Why am I getting segfault when changing the signature of main?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I am trying to get my feet into C, and wrote this program that displays a kb of my RAM in a random location. Here is the code, and it works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char *mem;
    for(int i =0; i < 1024; i++){
        mem++;
        printf("%c", *mem);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After that, I did the following change in my code, and I get segfaults every time I run my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>


// Just added this signature
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *mem;
    for(int i =0; i < 1024; i++){
        mem++;
        printf("%c", *mem);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My spider senses tell me that the segfaults I get are random, and should also be caused in the first example, but running the different programs again and again makes it look like predictable behaviour.

```
$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: spider senses are right once again!

Comment: ".. a kb of **my** RAM"? No. An uninitialized variable can point to anything - not 'your' RAM per se.

Comment: You *can't* "display a kb of my RAM in a random location".  The operating system will not allow it.  You can only access memory that has been allocated to your process, and the only way to _know_ which memory that is, is by deriving pointers from other valid pointers and/or from OS memory allocation primitives.

Comment: Why the downvote? Just because an answer may be obvious to some, it doesn't mean it's a poorly asked question. It shows code, expected behavior, actual behavior along with the error message

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both your snippets invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you try to

1. Go out of bound (`mem++;`, with no allocation)
2. use uninitialized values (accessing `*mem` )

with the current version.

Remember, pointers do not magically inherit (or acquire) memory, you need to make a pointer point to something valid, in general.

Comment: Maybe I'm tired, but go out of bounds of what ?

Comment: I think another way to say it is, you're moving the pointer to a place in memory that you didn't allocate. Out of bounds is memory that the OS didn't assign to you

Comment: @Quentin with zero allocation, moving the pointer will take you out of bound anyway, isn't it? :)

Comment: How can you go "out of bounds" with an **indeterminate** pointer value?

Comment: @JuanMendes: Memory is not necessarily assigned by an OS. That is not a requirement by the standard and wrong for most running systems.

Comment: @Olaf Would saying "invalid memory access" be better? Out of bound access is invalid memory access, isn;t it?

Comment: @Olaf Any memory that you didn't allocate yourself may end up in an illegal address, restricted by the OS; that's why you have undefined behavior. Some times it will segfault, sometimes it won't, as the OP explained.

Comment: @JuanMendes: You never programmed bare-metal embedded systems, did you? Interestingly now you write " allocate yourself ", while you wrote above " that the OS didn't assign to you". What is it now? (hint: none is always true and there are other options)

Comment: @SouravGhosh: I actually meant that there are no bounds, as the pointer does not point to an object. But ok, in a more universal sense, one can call it out-of-bounds ("array of size 0"):-)

Comment: I think I got it, but since I didn't allocate any memory shouldn't the first snippet always fail? I mean, I didn't allocate a single byte of memory, and when executed I could see my memory contents clearly. I could even see some environmental variables among other garbage. Shouldn't this part of memory be inaccessible as well?

Comment: @Loupax read the linked article about undefined behavior. Its simply undefined.

Comment: @SouravGhosh so in other words, "The first snippet should not work, but it does so `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`"

Comment: @Olaf True, I haven't worked on bare metal, but I did write C code for the first 6 years of my career. I'm not sure what your dichotomy is though so let me explain what I mean. Yes, it's both: I allocated it myself by asking the OS for a chunk of memory, either by dynamically allocating it with the `malloc` family of calls or on the stack with standard C declarations like `int a[10];`

Answer (score 4):

The value of `mem` is undefined (not initialized), but not random.  If before main is called, other C runtime functions, are called, then the slot of stack used by `mem` may have a valid pointer within it.  Adding parameters to main changes which slot is used and changes behaviour.  This can mean the code doesn't crash, although it is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize `mem`. I guess you're trying to just read random memory, but that isn't allowed. For example, you may be trying to read memory that's used by a different process, or you may be trying to read some address that doesn't even exist in your computer.

By changing the signature for main, you've changed what random junk value is in `mem` to start with. The way it probably works is that `mem` is taking a random value from some register. When you modified the function signature, `argc` and `argv` are using those registers instead. Therefor `mem` is getting a different junk register value of a junk stack value. In any case, you shouldn't try to follow a junk pointer.

Just because it works in one example, only means you got lucky. You still should not do it. It's very likely it wouldn't work if any little thing was changed.

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize `mem`, so its contents are undefined.  When you attempt to either increment it with `++` or dereference the pointer, you get [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

One of the things that can happen with undefined behavior is that a program may appear to work normally, and making a seemingly unrelated change will cause a crash.

Comment: and out of bound, too. :)

Comment: `mem++` is undefined behaviour also

Comment: @Hogan only when the pointer points to an object that exists (or one past the end). Using `mem`'s value (without dereferencing) is also undefined

Comment: I see what you mean... just a case of semantics -- your point is, if you start with undefined -- do something defined to it, you still get undefined.  I agree -- it is like null in that way.

Comment: @Hogan: Wht is `NaN + 1.0`? ;-)